# fullPage.js not working in MVC view

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, fullpage.js

I have basic template layout and I try to add fullPage.js to my test view using this [directives](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#usage). my view looks like

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/fullpage")
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
    <div class="section">Some section</div>
</div>
@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/jquery.fullPage.js">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#fullpage').fullpage();
        });
    </script>
```

my fullpage bundle is

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/fullpage").Include(
                "~/Content/jquery-1.12.4.js",
                "~/Content/jquery.fullPage.js",
                "~/Content/vendors/scrolloverflow.min.js",
                "~/Content/vendors/jquery.easings.min.js"
                ));
```

And it doesn't seem to work in any way i try it. Any pointers?

Comment: have you tried navigating to the url `~/bundles/fullpage` and checking if it's there?

Comment: checked right now and it's there

Comment: Have you tried getting the bundle with a `Script` html tage eg `<script src="/bundles/fullpage" ></script>`

Comment: put @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/fullpage") at end of the page.

Comment: gets me the same result as earlier

Comment: checked in console whats wrong going on? or any error you find ?

Comment: @Sagar R doesn't seem to change anything

Comment: @Sagar R the only error i get is connection with ws://localhost:56465/2564f98e5d78448586b988277a541f6f/browserLinkSignalR/connect?transport=webSockets&connectionToken=... was broken

Comment: and element not found... i guess it's that